# SQL: How can I retrieve total amount from joined tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My tables

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
  id        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname VARCHAR(50),
  lastname  VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Payments (
  id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  amount      INT,
  customer_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerPayment FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES Customers (id)
);
```

I want to get total payment amount for all customers. Here is my try:

```
SELECT SUM(p.amount)
FROM Customers c
  JOIN Payments p
    ON c.id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY p
```

Comment: Just add `id` or `name` column in `group by` and `select`. `SELECT SUM(p.amount), p.id.. GROUP BY p.id`

Comment: In that case I'll get total amount for customers. But I'm trying to get total amount in general. I need a single value (sum), i.e. `12300`.

Comment: Then remove `group by` and `join` just `select SUM(p.amount) FROM 
  Payments p`

Comment: Yeap, it works. Ok, but if I don't have constraints and in my Payments table customer_id is null, in that case how can I exclude this id from total sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select sum(p.amount) as total
from
    customers c
    inner join
    payments p on c.id = p.customer_id
```

If there can be null values in `payments.customer_id` the join condition will exclude them.

Or cheaper without the join:

```
select sum(amount) as total
from payments
where customer_id is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

remove group by from query..

```
  SELECT SUM(p.amount)
FROM Customers c
  JOIN Payments p
    ON c.id = p.customer_id
```